# Kivy Exits Loop while using Pillow

Tags: python, kivy, python-imaging-library

I've got simple kivy app that takes in a three `.tif` files and creates a copy of each one. For some reason, Kivy is automatically exiting out of the `for loop` when ever something is done to an image. The function has no problems outside of kivy. No errors are being generated in my terminal either. It seems that there is a conflict with using `pillow`, but it is difficult to troubleshoot with no error message.

**main.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from PIL import Image
import os

path_in = 'D:/TIF_STORAGE/'
path_out = 'D:/Convert/'


def manip_img(in_pth, out_pth):
    i = 0
    for img in os.listdir(in_pth):
        img_open = Image.open(in_pth + img)
        print(img_open)   
        # Does not get to the next step
        conv = img_open.copy()
        print(conv)       
        conv.save(out_pth + str(i) + '.tif')        
        i = i + 1

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class MainWindow(Screen):
    def run_main(self):
        manip_img(path_in, path_out)
            
            
kv_main = Builder.load_file('main.kv')


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv_main
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

**main.kv**

```
WindowManager:
    MainWindow:

<MainWindow>
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Button:
            text: "Run"
            on_release: root.run_main()
```

**Output**

```
(GUI) D:\KIVY_new\testing>python main.py
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\name\.kivy\logs\kivy_21-12-03_63.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\name\anaconda3\envs\GUI\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.8.12 (default, Oct 12 2021, 03:01:40) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\name\anaconda3\envs\GUI\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 186 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.6.0 NVIDIA 496.76'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'NVIDIA Corporation'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080/PCIe/SSE2'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 6
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.60 NVIDIA'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <32768>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
<PIL.TiffImagePlugin.TiffImageFile image mode=RGBA size=800x800 at 0x1CF5C1497F0>

(GUI) D:\KIVY_new\testing>
```

**simple .py script**

```
from PIL import Image
import os

path_in = 'D:/TIF_STORAGE/'
path_out = 'D:/Convert/'


def manip_img(in_pth, out_pth):
    i = 0
    for img in os.listdir(in_pth):
        img_open = Image.open(in_pth + img)
        print(img_open)
        # Does get to the next step
        conv = img_open.copy()
        print(conv)
        conv.save(out_pth + str(i) + '.tif') 
        i = i + 1
        
        
manip_img(path_in, path_out)
```

**Output**

```
(GUI) D:\>python delete_script.py
<PIL.TiffImagePlugin.TiffImageFile image mode=RGBA size=800x800 at 0x24155CC6DF0>
<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGBA size=800x800 at 0x24155CA7130>
<PIL.TiffImagePlugin.TiffImageFile image mode=RGBA size=800x800 at 0x241578E3BE0>
<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGBA size=800x800 at 0x24155CC6DF0>
<PIL.TiffImagePlugin.TiffImageFile image mode=RGBA size=800x800 at 0x241578E3760>
<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGBA size=800x800 at 0x241578D5160>
```

Comment: That is weird. I don't know the solution, but I remember kivy to be pretty hackish at times. Hence my suggestion: try resetting `stdout` and `stderr` by doing `sys.stdout = sys.stderr = sys.__stdout__`. If errors are thrown but hidden by kivy or pillow, this will show them again. If this doesn't work, check if the loop ends by adding a print statement at the end of the loop. Attach a debugger, perhaps.

Comment: I know this is not what you're asking for, but I'd also like to recommend staying clear from kivy. I've sunk to much time trying to solve obscure erros. I've just looked at the docs, it looks exactly like it did 3 years ago. They're trying to reinvent the wheel by building another GUI library for python. If your targeting tech savvy people (perhaps even yourself), I recomment to use jupyter for GUIs. If not, switch to tkinter or dear gui. Consider making it terminal only. Kivy is an ambitious project that lacks work to match the ambition.

Comment: Getting your dev env to work properly is only the first time sink... the next will be to ship your application.

Comment: Ended up downgrading `pillow` and it worked, but I've also had the problem with the downgraded version. It's been difficult to reproduce recently. Like you said, it's been pretty glitchy.

Comment: Always appreciate the feedback! I choose kivy over tkinter because I read that tkinter was a bit out of date and that kivy was supposed to be the "new" thing. I didn't know jupyter could be used for GUIs. I'll defiantly take a look at `dear`. I'll probably finish out using kivy with this app and look through the other ones for future apps!

Comment: The only application ship library that I've been introduced to has been `pyinstaller`. Probably going to keep this version in house for now. Again, appreciate the feedback and support!

Comment: I'll post again if I ever figure out what the issue is!

Comment: sure, you're welcome :) You can create interactive widgets in jupyter ([intro](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Basics.html)) and hide code of individual cells, at least on google colab, giving you a decently graphical application for simple tasks. But you need to spin up a jupyter instance every time you use it.